# In R: How can I plug in values for my independent variables in a linear model?

Tags: r, parameter-passing, linear-regression

I am working with a linear model that has 3 variables and interactions. Instead of manually typing the formula out and typing in values for each of the variables, say X Y and Z, how can I tell R to give me the predicted value for a given X Y and Z?

I.e. 
if

```
model=lm(VP~G+P+Z+G:Z+P:Z+G:P+P:G:Z,data=xyz)

'[output with beta coefficients]'
```

how can I pass in value of G P and Z to the linear model without manually typing in each term's individual beta coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

Use `predict()`. Read all the details on the help page which can be accessed via `?predict`. Here's an example using the example from `?lm`

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2,10,20, labels=c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
```

And predict:

```
> predict(lm.D9, newdata=data.frame(group = c("Ctl", "Trt")))
    1     2 
5.032 4.661
```

Note the use of the `newdata` parameter and how I passed the new values to be predicted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to predict from a model with all two (and three-)-way interactions, your model can be simplified to

```
 model=lm(VP ~ (G+P+Z)^3, data=xyz)   # see ?formula
```

When you predict from the "model" object you need to supply a dataframe with values named G,P and Z

```
pred123 <- predict(model, newdata=data.frame(G=1, P=2, Z=3) )
```

If you wanted to construct all possible combinations of values for a particular choice of individual values, the expand.grid function will be very useful:

```
 pred.all <- predict(modlel, newdat=expand.grid(G;1:3, P=2:5, Z=6:8) )
```

Comment: Just a small point but they do have the three way interaction in their model.

Comment: Ah, Didn't notice, Will fix.